# POST data from input within loop

Tags: laravel

I have a lot of products from a database. I display them with a loop. When a user clicks "more", I want to display its details. The problem is, for example: I have four products A, B, C, and D. When a user clicks A's details, it displays D's details or randomly. How can I fix this? This is my code:

```
<form action="details" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@foreach($images as $image)
        <div class="card" >

          <div class="card-inside1" >
              <div class="center">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<?php echo asset('images').'/'.$image->image1 ?>" alt="Card image" >
              </div>

              <div class="card-body">
                <input type="text" name="imagename" value="{{$image->product_name}}"></input>
                  <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="more" class="btn btn-primary ">More</button>
              </div>
          </div>

         </div>
    @endforeach
</form>
```

route

```
 Route::post("details",'UserController@detail');
```

controller

```
 public function detail(Request $req)
 {
  $productname = $req->input('imagename');
  return $productname;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of using a form to accomplish  what you want.

```
@foreach($images as $image)
  <div class="card" >
    <div class="card-inside1" >
        <div class="center">
          <img clas="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<?php echo asset('images').'/'.$image->image1 ?>" alt="Card image" >
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <input type="text" name="imagename" value="{{$image->product_name}}"></input>
            <a href="{{url('details/'.$image->product_name)}}" class="btn btn-primary ">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Route:

```
Route::get("details/{imagename}",'UserController@detail');
```

Controller:

```
public function detail(Request $req)
{
   $productname = $req->imagename;
   return $productname;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The reason why is taking the last product is because you are sending all products through the form. and it takes the last one that sends, not the one you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

view
`@foreach($images as $image)
    <a href="{{ route('product.show', $product->id) }}">{{ $product->name }}</a>
@endforeach`

web.php

```
Route::get("details/{id}",'ProductController@show')->name('product.show');
```

ProductController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return $product
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cruorzy